# Setting value in Java array returns error

Tags: java, arrays

This method is supposed to set a value in an array, given its index. The error is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which occurs on the line:

```
 GrowingArray [index] = value;
```

However, I've done some research and using `array [index] = value` seems to be a legitimate way to set a value in an array. A pointer in the right direction would be helpful.

```
public void set (int index, int value) {
  if (index <= GrowingArray.length) {
    GrowingArray[index] = value;
  } else {
    int [] destination = new int [12/10*GrowingArray.length];
    destination [index] = value;
    System.arraycopy(destination, 0, GrowingArray, 0, destination.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java arrays have 0 based indices (like 99% of things in computer science), so checking `<=` (instead that `<` ) will allow, for example the index 4 for an array of size 4, which will end out of bonds.

```
if (index <= GrowingArray.length){
  GrowingArray[index] = value;
```

In addition `12/10` is an integer division which yields `1`, if you want to increase capacity by 20% you should use `float` values, eg:

```
int newCapacity = (int)(oldCapacity*1.2f);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that <= allowed my array check to go out of bounds. I changed it to < as you said to, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

in java array's index start with 0,

so when index == GrowingArray.length, the max index of GrowingArray is [index - 1]

what about try to change

```
if (index <= GrowingArray.length)
```

to

```
if (index < GrowingArray.length){
```